# Run Function in jQuery on Page Load and Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function in jQuery that I would like to run on Page Load and on Change. How would I do this? I currently only have the change part..

```
    $('input[name=INPUTNAME]').change(function(){
        ....
    });
```

Comment: You mean $(document).ready(...) ? https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I want the same function to be ran on page ready and on change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to your input change listener and also call the same function on document ready.

```js
$(function() {

  yourFunction();
  
  $("input").change(yourFunction);
  
});

function yourFunction() {
  alert("foo bar");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name=INPUTNAME]", function(){})
```

Reference
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This does not work on initial page load. I have an input that has a default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(yourFunctionName());
  $('input[name=INPUTNAME]').on('change', yourFunctionName());

  function yourFunctionName(){
    //function body
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Try this. Basically, we have a function and call it on input change and when the document is ready.